# Kivy error: AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__' on self.root.ids

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Can someone help me why the button doesn't do anything and why the self.root.ids.container.add_widget(
OneLineListItem(text=f"Single-line item {i}") gives out an error,

"AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'"

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from logging import root
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from KVFile import KVee




class Entry(BoxLayout):

    pass

class Test(MDApp):

    bx = BoxLayout()
    
    def build(self):
        
        kvv =  Builder.load_string(KVee)
       
        
        self.bx.add_widget(kvv)

       


        return self.bx
        
    def testFunc(self):

        print("meow!")

    def listItems(self):

        self.dialog = MDDialog(
                title="Task Entry",
                type="custom",
                content_cls=Entry(),
                buttons=[
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="CANCEL", text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,
                        #on_release=self.dialog.
                    ),
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="OK", text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,
                        on_release=lambda x:self.add()
                    ),
                ],
            )
        self.dialog.open()
        
    def add(self):
        self.root.ids.container.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=f"Single-line item "))
        
    

if __name__ == "__main__":

    Test().run()
```

Im really not that advanced in kivy, id really appreciate it if you guys could help me out,
thanks you so much in advance!

Here's the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 861, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'container'
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Users\Acer\Desktop\Proj\Python\Laboratory\help.py", line 65, in <module>
     Test().run()
   File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 950, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 582, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 347, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 391, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 308, in post_dispatch_input
     wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\behaviors\ripple_behavior.py", line 296, in on_touch_up
     return super().on_touch_up(touch)
   File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\button.py", line 982, in on_touch_up
     return super().on_touch_up(touch)
   File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 179, in on_touch_up
     self.dispatch('on_release')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 705, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1248, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1172, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "c:\Users\Acer\Desktop\Proj\Python\Laboratory\help.py", line 51, in <lambda>
     on_release=lambda x:self.add()
   File "c:\Users\Acer\Desktop\Proj\Python\Laboratory\help.py", line 58, in add
     self.root.ids.container.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=f"Single-line item "))
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 864, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough .

Answer (score 0):

First lets look on `MDApp` class:

```
class MDApp(App, FpsMonitoring):
    theme_cls = ObjectProperty()
    """
    Instance of :class:`~ThemeManager` class.
    .. Warning:: The :attr:`~theme_cls` attribute is already available
        in a class that is inherited from the :class:`~MDApp` class.
        The following code will result in an error!
    .. code-block:: python
        class MainApp(MDApp):
            theme_cls = ThemeManager()
            theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"
    .. Note:: Correctly do as shown below!
    .. code-block:: python
        class MainApp(MDApp):
            def build(self):
                self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"
    :attr:`theme_cls` is an :class:`~kivy.properties.ObjectProperty`.
    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.theme_cls = ThemeManager()
```

It inherits from `App` and from `FpsMonitoring` classes, you can read more about multiple inheritance in (here)[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiple-inheritance-in-python/]

Lets dive into both classes:
`FpsMonitoring`:

```
class FpsMonitoring:
    """Adds a monitor to display the current FPS in the toolbar."""

    def fps_monitor_start(self):
        from kivy.core.window import Window

        from kivymd.utils.fpsmonitor import FpsMonitor

        monitor = FpsMonitor()
        monitor.start()
        Window.add_widget(monitor)
```

and, `App` implementation can be found at -https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/app.py (doc is too long for pasting it here...)

`root` var is actually from `Builder` type (can be found at line 696 in the link above, and the implementation at https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/lang/builder.py), and Builder type is not implementing **getattr** method! so, in case you want to use it, you will need to find another way of accessing `ids` at `self.root`.